# Why is casting from char to std::byte potentially undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The `std::byte` of C++17 is required to be enum class:

```
enum class byte : unsigned char {};
```

We may want to use that `std::byte` to represent raw memory instead of one of `char`s since it is more type-safe, has its byte-specific operators defined and can't promote to `int` out of blue like `char`s do. We need to use explicit casts or `to_integer` to convert `std::byte` to other integers. However from lot of  sources we still get `char` (or more likely whole buffers of `char`) and so may want to convert it:

```
void fn(char c)
{
    std::byte b = static_cast<std::byte>(c);
    // ... that may invoke undefined behavior, read below
}
```

The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined so `std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed` may be `true`. Therefore above `c` may have negative values that are outside of range of `unsigned char`.

Now in C++17 standard in 8.2.9 Static cast [expr.static.cast] paragraph 10
we can read that:

> A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to
>   a complete enumeration type. The value is unchanged if the original
>   value is within the range of the enumeration values (10.2). Otherwise,
>   the behavior is undefined.

And from 10.2 we can see that the mentioned range is range of underlying type. Therefore to avoid undefined behavior we have to write more code. For example we can add a cast to `unsigned char` to achieve defined effects of modular arithmetic during cast:

```
void fn(char c)
{
    std::byte b = static_cast<std::byte>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
    // ... now we have done it in portable manner?
}
```

Did I misunderstand something? Isn't that over-abundantly complicated and restrictive? Why can't the `enum class` that has unsigned underlying type follow modular arithmetic like its underlying type does? Note that the whole row of casts is most likely compiled into nothing by compiler anyway. The `char` when it is signed has to be two's complement since C++14 and so its bitwise representation has to be same as after modular arithmetic conversion to `unsigned char`. Who benefits from that formal undefined behavior and how?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is going to be fixed in the [next standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#10):

> A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a complete enumeration type. If the enumeration type has a fixed underlying type, **the value is first converted to that type by integral conversion, if necessary, and then to the enumeration type**. If the enumeration type does not have a fixed underlying type, the value is unchanged if the original value is within the range of the enumeration values ([dcl.enum]), and otherwise, the behavior is undefined

[Here's](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1766) the rationale behind the change from (C++11) unspecified to (C++17) undefined:
￼

> Although issue 1094 clarified that the value of an expression of enumeration type might not be within the range of the values of the enumeration after a conversion to the enumeration type (see 8.2.9 [expr.static.cast] paragraph 10), **the result is simply an unspecified value. This should probably be strengthened to produce undefined behavior, in light of the fact that undefined behavior makes an expression non-constant.**

And [here's](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2338) the rationale behind the C++2a fix:

> The specifications of std::byte (21.2.5 [support.types.byteops]) and bitmask (20.4.2.1.4 [bitmask.types]) have revealed a problem with the integral conversion rules, according to which both those specifications have, in the general case, **undefined behavior**. The problem is that a conversion to an enumeration type has undefined behavior unless the value to be converted is in the range of the enumeration.
>
> For enumerations with an unsigned fixed underlying type, **this requirement is overly restrictive, since converting a large value to an unsigned integer type is well-defined**.

Comment: Thanks for answer about brighter future. I was also interested in rationale behind current situation. In C++11 that added underlying types to enum we had "Otherwise, the resulting enumeration value is unspecified." So there had to be some logic that made the committee to strengthen it into "demons from our noses" in C++17.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: I've added some additional information to my answer.